# How do I get the value of NotifyIcon.Icon property programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I know this is such a noob question, but I am trying to learn and test. One of my self-imposed challenges is creating a NotifyIcon in the systray (easy) and then clicking a button and making the icon change on interval from green to red based on the current icon value. However, when I try to read the value of NotifyIcon.Icon, it is just (Icon). I expect it to be an ico file I have in Properties.Resources (i.e. Properties.Resources.icon.ico).

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TEST_NotifyIconChange
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        private ContextMenuStrip ContextMenuStrip_System_Tray = new ContextMenuStrip();
        private DispatcherTimer iconAnimationTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            iconAnimationTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            iconAnimationTimer.Tick += IconAnimationTimer_Tick;
            iconAnimationTimer.IsEnabled = false;

            ResetAll();
        }

        private void ResetAll()
        {
            notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip_System_Tray;
            notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon_green;
            notifyIcon.Text = "I am just a standard icon";
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        }

        private void ChangeColorButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (iconAnimationTimer.IsEnabled == false)
            {
                iconAnimationTimer.IsEnabled = true;
                iconAnimationTimer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                iconAnimationTimer.Stop();
                iconAnimationTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void IconAnimationTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (notifyIcon.Icon == Properties.Resources.icon_green)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changing to red");
                notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon_red;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Changing to green");
                notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon_green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `notifyIcon.Icon == Properties.Resources.icon_green` will never return true, because everytime that you call `Properties.Resources.icon_green`, it creates and returns a new icon.

Comment: Store the state separately using an enum: `enum State { Red, Green }` and declare a field `State state;` and then `if (state == State.Green)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyIcon.Icon == Properties.Resources.icon_green` will never return `true`, because every time that you call it, it returns a new instance of the Icon.

You don't need to track the assigned icon; instead, you need to track of the **status** and based on the *status*, assign an icon. To track the status you can use `Tag` property of `NotifyIcon` or a member field of the `Form`. But do not look at the Icon property as a status indicator.

Just in case you are interested to compare two `Icon` objects to see whether they are same icon, you can use the following method:

```
bool AreIconsEqual(Icon ico1, Icon ico2)
{
    byte[] bytes1, bytes2;
    using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ico1.Save(fs);
        bytes1 = fs.ToArray();
    }
    using (var fs = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ico2.Save(fs);
        bytes2 = fs.ToArray();
    }
    return bytes1.SequenceEqual(bytes2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza! I actually implemented an integer value that counted up every time the timer ticked, determined whether it was odd or even (since I only have 2 icons), and set the icon appropriately. However, I will practice your advice above to see if it performs better or can help me scale when I have other scenarios with more icons. I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem :) The counter/flag/status definitely performs better than the `AreIconsEqual`.

Comment: And also a status variable is better because it represents a state in the business logic, but the icons represent a states in the presentation layer. The two concerns presentation layer and business logic should be separated. Your logic should not relay on the presentation layer. See: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: True, as it's already mentioned in the answer, icons should not be used for tracking status. `AreIconsEqual` is there just to show the OP how to compare two icons, which is not possible by notifyIcon.Icon == Properties.Resources.icon_green.

Comment: @BobWehadababyitsaboy I believe the post answers your question. It would be nice if you upvote/accept the answer, however, feel free to keep it as it is, if you think otherwise.